# как обратиться ко вложенной функции (def greeting())?

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу сделать парсер в телеграмм с периодическим выводом информации в чат.
Нужно обратиться к greeteng,чтобы инфа выводилась
Подскажите, я вообще на правильном пути? Или я лох и надо делать и оформлять по другому?

код:

```
def telegram_bot(token):

    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['price'])
    def send_text(message):

        if message.text.lower() == "/price":
            try:
                def greeting():
                    response = requests.get(url='https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_usd')
                    data = response.json()
                    btc_price = f"BTC: {round(data.get('btc_usd').get('last'), 2)}$\n"

                    print(btc_price)
                greeting()
                telegram_bot(token)

            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                bot.send_message(
                    message.chat.id,
                    "Damn...Something was wrong...")

        bot.infinity_polling()


def main():
    schedule.every(4).seconds.do(greeting)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Сделайте отдельный поток (Thread) который по таймеру (shedule кстати использовать вообще нет надобности, просто бесконечный цикл с time.sleep(4)) будет обновлять прайс в какой нибудь глобальной переменной. А бот в другом потоке будет брать данные из переменной тогда, когда они ему нужны

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите `greeting()` за `send_text()` и просто вызывайте её

Comment: Спасибо за совет! А разве если я вынесу гритинг за сенд текст, то  каким образом бот будет отправлять сообщения с информацией?

Comment: Напишите в том месте `greeting()` и все